# Mass of particle w.r.t. dimension

Tags: particle-physics, mass, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

I heard in a lecture recently - just as a comment - that a particle which is massive in say $D=4$ can be seen as a massless particle in higher dimensions and vice versa. Our prof didn't give any equations to explain this and I don't really see how this comes about. What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your professor was thinking of a massive [Kaluza-Klein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) particle, whose 4D (rest-)mass $m_{4}$ from a 5D perspective could consist entirely of its (quantized) momentum$^1$ $p_5$ along the extra (small compact) fifth dimension.

In detail: Let us work in units where the speed of light $c=1$ is one. Recall the special relativistic formula for the energy $E$ in $D$-dimensional spacetime:

$$\tag{1} E^2 ~=~ m_{D}^2 + {\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}~=~ m_{D}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} p_i^2. $$

Next let us specialize to $D=5$, and define the 4D rest-mass from a 4D perspective as

$$\tag{2} m_{4}^2~:=~  E^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{3} p_i^2 ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ m_{5}^2+ p_5^2 ~\stackrel{m_{5}=0}{=}~  p_5^2 .$$

--

$^1$ The momentum $p_5$ along the fifth dimension (i.e. the fourth spatial dimension) should more properly and systematically be called $p_4$, but that notation would likely cause confusion.

Comment: But how would that look like in formula? Say I have a four-momentum in D=4: $p^2=m^2$ holds. Now in 5D $\tilde{p}^2=0$ should hold and somehow going down in D would produce m^2. I just don't see how.

Comment: Thanks! So in other words the sum in the above equation should be equal to $-m_0^2$, right? So, the 5th dimension gets compactified and 4D "inherets" the mass, so to speak?

Comment: I updated the answer.